# How do I model a boolean AND-evaluation in Promela non-atomically?

Tags: promela

How do I model a boolean AND-evaluation in Promela non-atomically ?

I want to model the statement `while (flag[j] == true && victim == i)` where the AND-evaluation should be done non-atomically.

How is this possible?

Comment: My answer is not worthy of even an up-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loop:
if 
:: flag[j] != true -> goto done
:: else
fi;

if 
:: victim != i -> goto done
:: else
fi;

/* body of 'while' */

goto loop;
done:

/* after 'while' */
```

Note, although I don't have a Spin environment in front of me, what makes you think the conditional is atomic in the first place?  I'd test with something like:

```
byte i = 0

i++ >= 0 && i-- >= 0

never { assert (1 == i) }
```

But, either way, the first code above shows how to make it non-atomic if need be.

Comment: Sorry, I've been inactive lately.
Thanks a lot for your answer - I appreciate it.